# git restore submodules - submodule directory created but empty

Tags: git

When pushing to production the submodules are not updated. The submodule root directory is created but no files inside

post-receive

```
#/bin/sh
cd /var/www/repo
git --work-tree=. --git-dir=/var/git_repos/repo.git checkout master -f
git --work-tree=. --git-dir=/var/git_repos/repo.git git submodule update --init --recursive
```

When browsing through github the submodules are present and linked with latest version

When I run `git push production master` from remote I get this

```
# git push production master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 284 bytes | 284.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Already on 'master'
remote: git: 'git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
remote:
remote: The most similar command is
remote:         init
To ssh://domain.com/var/git_repos/repo.git
   a710c83..6d75702  master -> master
```

Comment: `git restore` is the wrong command to use. Use `git submodule update --init` or similar.

Comment: @torek which command should I then use?

Comment: have updated my question with new post-receive. The submodules are still empty folders

Comment: You have an extra git in your submodule command

Comment: Ah, the error is clear: you used to have `git <options> restore`, now you have `git <options> git submodule`. Why did you remember to omit the second `git` the first time, but not the second time? :-)

Comment: I have edited my answer to point out where there should *not* be a second git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in [our discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225230/discussion-between-vonc-and-clarkk), I would first use [`git submodule update`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--ltpathgt82308203), because it will:

- update the registered submodules to match what the superproject expects by cloning missing submodules,
- fetch missing commits in submodules and
- update the working tree of the submodules.

The second point "fetch missing commits in submodules" is the missing step which triggers, when you push to your base repo, the error message

```
remote: fatal: failed to unpack tree object d09a53c53a7bd222df4869e66b9e45acee45e094
remote: error: Submodule 'php/repo/utils' could not be updated.
```

So try with the script:

```sh
#/bin/sh
cd /var/www/repo
git --work-tree=. --git-dir=/var/git_repos/repo.git checkout master -f
git --work-tree=. --git-dir=/var/git_repos/repo.git submodule update --remote
                                                  ^^^^
                                                (no git there)
```

Comment: `git --work-tree=. --git-dir=/var/git_repos/repo.git submodule update --remote` doesn't work either

Comment: @clarkk Does not work, as in "not working when I push to production machine and trigger the post-receive hook script that way"? In other words, would that same script work if you cal it directly on the production server?

Comment: I always call this from remote (local dev)

Comment: @clarkk OK so through the git push process, triggering the hook. I was asking because in our previous discussion, the script was working, but you were testing it directly on production.

Comment: @clarkk For testing, can you add in the hook script, at the line after the first one (after `#!/bin/bash`) `unset GIT_DIR`? (keep the checkout and submodule commands after the new unset)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225290/discussion-between-vonc-and-clarkk).